# What is Firebug telling me is wrong with my HTTP POST?

Tags: post, firebug, symfony-forms

Im trying to figure out what is wrong with my POST data, or Ajax call.

Im using Symfony to create a form, and Ajax to collect and pass the data. Each time I do a POST request I use Firebug's *Net* panel to look at my POST data. My POST is breaking somewhere, but I can't tell where. The only thing I can see here is when I look at Firebug I am seeing the POST looks different there for each example (the parameters are present in one, and not present in the other), but they should be identical, right? Is this a clue? I don't know how to interpret this, I don't know enough about Firebug, and its obviously not intuitive enough here for this particular issue.

Is this telling me my data isn't encoded correctly?

Here is a non-working example. Notice, "Parameters" is missing. All I see is the "Source" serialized/encoded data:

[image: broken form]

Now, in the example below, this is what I expect to see. Notice, this one not only contains the "Source" portion and the source data looks identical (but can use a 2nd pair of eyes on this), but there is another section called "Parameters". Why is this elusively missing in the first example and what does the missing "Parameters" mean?

[image: proper working form]  [image: proper form 2nd half]

I'm attaching the headers here, too. Maybe this will explain the problem.  And posting these here now I do see the different `Content-Type`, but I think most of my testing was done before I was sending that header.

broken form headers [image: broken form]

working form headers [image: working form]

Either something is wrong with the POST data or might I be be missing the Ajax `dataType: 'json'`, or something?

Comment: ok i fixed one problem, the content-type was being accidentally passed as `application/json`, now the form data does look correct.  SO i guess i was just not loking correctly at the headers.  Next time im missing parameters, im going straight to the header data!

Comment: If changing the `Content-Type` fixed your problem, you should post your comment as an answer and accept it, so others can refer to it.

Comment: right, so i have a dilemma.  i have problems with my POST still, its not related to the title.  but its directly rated.  althought this DID anser my question, and i would like to close this thread as such, i dont want to get flamed for starting a thread and having it wrongly called duplicate.  The problem im having now is probable still related to either the symfony form, or my js code.  Furthermore, i was going to try to fix it myself before asking for input on that, so therefore this post was kind of on hold until then.  Any suggestions?

Comment: ok i split that into a new topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866304/symfony-form-not-coming-back-valid-do-i-have-form-object-issues , and i would like to keep this post open until all js problems resolved pertaining to the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the wrong content type set in the headers, when the data is sent back, and inspected in Firebug, it can't pull them apart as parameters, unless it knows its form encoded data. If the header declares a different type, then if the data *is* indeed form url encoded, then the browser doesn't parse it as such, therefore can't break it apart into its parameter elements.

So when you make your call, be sure the content type is being sent as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` in your Ajax call.