# symfony form not coming back valid, do i have form object issues?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, post

i have tried various ways, but i cant get form to come back `isValid()` so i wanted to make sure i have this portion correct first.

```
    <?php
    namespace ABC\DeBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller,
        Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route,
        Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template,
        Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method,
        Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
        Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException,
        Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface,
        Symfony\Component\Form\Forms,
        Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationExtension,
        Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension,
        Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation,
        Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length,
        Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank,
        Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception,
        Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response,
        ABC\CoreBundle\Controller\CoreController;

    class DoSomethingController extends CoreController

{

    protected $debug = FALSE;

    public function doSomethingAction(Request $request)
    {
        /**
         * build the form here
         *
         * Either use out custom build form object
         * $form = $formFactory->createBuilder('form', $defaultData)
         *
         * Or alternatively, use the default formBuilder
         * $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
         */
        $validator = Validation::createValidator();

        $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
            ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension())
            ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
            ->getFormFactory();

        $defaultData = array(
            'comment' => 'Type your comment here',
            'name' => 'Type your name here',
            'resources' => '{}',
            'warning' => 'Warning, your still in debug mode on your controller.php'
        );

        //$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        $form = $formFactory->createBuilder('form', $defaultData)
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('do_something'))
            ->add("emails", 'text', array(
                'label' => "Recipient's email address (separate with a comma)",
                'constraints' => array(// constraints here
                ),
            ))
            ->add('comment', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => "Leave a comment",
            ))
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => "Your name",
                'constraints' => array(// constraints here
                ),
            ))
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'label' => "Your email address",
                'constraints' => array(// constraints here
                ),
            ))
            ->add('copy', 'checkbox', array(
                'label' => "Send me a copy",
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('cancel', 'button', array(
                'label' => "Cancel",
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-branded'),
            ))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => "Email Resources",
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-branded'),
            ));

        //make resources visible by putting them into a text box
        $resourceInputType = $this->debug ? 'text' : 'hidden';
        $form->add('resources', $resourceInputType, array(
            'constraints' => array(// constraints here
            ),
        ));

        //add a visible warning input box, so we know were on debug, we don't want this released to live on debug.
        $this->debug ? ($form = $form->add('warning', 'text')) : null;

        $form .= $form->getForm();

        //alternatively
        //$form->bind($_POST[$form->getName()]);
        //$form->handleRequest($request);

        //validate
        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();

            //run some data checks, then fire it off
            $something = $this->DoSomething($data);
            return $something;
            //$return=array("responseCode"=>200,  "data"=>$data);
            // $return=json_encode($return); //json encode the array
            // return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));//make sure it has the correct content type
        }else
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump('form is coming back as not isValid(), make sure debug is off, heres our errors list:<br>');
        var_dump($form->getErrorsAsString());
        echo '</pre>';
    }

        //its not a POST, or  POST is invalid, so display the form
        return $this->render($this->someTemplate, array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

1) Im a bit confused (oop wise) on the way to pass around this form object during conditional manipulation.  Do i need to concatenate it when manipulating it or what does symfony offer to avoid this, or am i just passing the object around wrong?  see this example to understand better this question. e.g.  `$form .= $form->getForm();` How would i properly concatenate this form object during manipulation, like i did when i used the ternary, to convine myself that when i pass this object around, its teh same object, and not a new one.

2) see any other problems that might be causing the breakage?

**EDIT** @Chausser
this is the latest code, streamlined a bit, that i am working with now using some apparently rare exmples found here http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Form/Forms.html.  its still not coming back `isValid()` . Please compare my former, and new usage example of the form object.

```
 <?php
 /**
  * @param Request $request
  * @Route("/do/something", name="do_something",  options={"expose"=true})
  * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
  * @return mixed
  */
public function doSomethingAction(Request $request)
{
    $defaultData = array(
        'comment' => 'Type your comment here',
        'name' => 'Type your name here',
        'resources' => '{}',
        'warning' => 'Warning, your still in debug mode on your controller.php'
    );

    $resourceInputType = $this->debug ? 'text' : 'hidden';

    $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactory();
    $form = $formFactory
        ->createBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('do_something'))
        ->add("emails", 'text', array(
            'label' => "Recipient's email address (separate with a comma)",
            'constraints' => array(// constraints here
            ),
        ))
        ->add('comment', 'textarea', array(
            'label' => "Leave a comment",
        ))
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => "Your name",
            'constraints' => array(// constraints here
            ),
        ))
        ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'label' => "Your email address",
            'constraints' => array(// constraints here
            ),
        ))
        ->add('copy', 'checkbox', array(
            'label' => "Send me a copy",
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('cancel', 'button', array(
            'label' => "Cancel",
            'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-branded'),
        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'label' => "Email Resources",
            'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-branded'),
        ))
        ->add('resources', $resourceInputType, array(
            'constraints' => array(// constraints here
            ),
        ))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    //validate
    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();

    //run some data checks, then fire it off
        $something = $this->DoSomething($data);
        return $something;
    //other options for returning
    //$return=array("responseCode"=>200,  "data"=>$data);
    // $return=json_encode($something); //json encode the array
    // return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));//make sure it has the correct content type
    } else {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump('form is coming back as not isValid(), make sure debug is off, heres our errors list:<br>');
        var_dump($form->getErrorsAsString());
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    //its not a POST, or  POST is invalid, so display the form
    return $this->render($this->someTemplate, array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**EDIT**
so now after my edits to get the form to not try and haldne the request, unless its teh POST request, not the GET request

```
    if($request && $request->getMethod() == 'POST'){

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    //validate
    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();

        //run some data checks, then fire it off
        $something = $this->DoSomething($data);
        return $something;
        //other options for returning
        //$return=array("responseCode"=>200,  "data"=>$data);
        // $return=json_encode($something); //json encode the array
        // return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));//make sure it has the correct content type
    } else {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump('form is coming back as not isValid(), make sure debug is off, heres our errors list:<br>');
        var_dump($form->getErrorsAsString());
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

which has led to the controller error mentioned below

Comment: I've never seen this `$form .= $form->getForm()` before for OOP. The `.=` is for concatenating assignment of strings _only._

Comment: ok, so far so good, so i wont do it that way, strings only?  that makes sense, no wonder i havent used it mcu in a long time, it was just for demonstration purposes so you can see one of the problem areas, so what would be the correct way then? i.e. can someone guarantee me that if i do it this way `$form = $form->getForm();` thats its continuing the object that i made above, and not getting a new blank form or someting....  or should i set this to a new variable each time i manipulate it?

Comment: I dont fully understand the error you are having? change `$form .= $form->getForm();` to `$form = $form->getForm();` (no dot). then uncomment the line `$form->handleRequest($request);` And you should have a working for, if not then you need to look at the form errors for the reason why `$errorsArray = $form->getErrors(true);`

Comment: ok thanks.  and what i have been testing with is `$form->getForm()`, i did receive a clear error message when i tried it that way (lol) that its not a string..  Then i have already added the handleRequest, the errors are coming back as empty, i have already tried this.  so i may be doing that part wrong.  ill add some code to see if maybe thats part of the problem.

Comment: @Chausser i updated the post to reflect the latest usage.

Comment: Get the errors of the form, `if($form->isValid()){...} else{ var_dump($form->getErrors(true)) }`

Comment: updated OP again, added my error check response.  im not able to get you  a copy of the actual response at the moment, but it was an ampty string `""` if i recall correctly. AHH, just got your post, would it make a difference doing it your way?  i will try that in a bit.

Comment: you know whats breaking now, thats holding me up, is the form itself, `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Expected argument of type "null", "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" given")  line 5`  i have got to get past this first now, however this may be a clue..  but i doubt it, its probably another error in itself..

Comment: i removed my comments about the symfony code change for the way you embed/render a controller in the twig template, this wasnt the problem why the template was breaking.  after i updated the code to use the new way, i had the same exact error after still. So im basically stuck here, until i figure out the template error.

Comment: ok, the error comes in RIGHT when it handles request, `handleRequest($request)` , however this is just the initial GET request to just load the form, not the POST request, so it shouldnt be handling the request.  what have i dont wrong here?

Comment: man this form is letting me have it.  so, i had to wrap a `if($form->isSubmitted()){` around the processing of the form(the handleRequest and isValid portions), it was bugging out so i stopped them from running altogether when its not yet submitted.  with that, i can move forward and get the errors now

Comment: Good god, now i am seeing this as the return from my form submit coming from the controller error `Expected argument of type "null", "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" given.  So there you go, wtf do i do now, anybody?

Comment: ok i might have another clue for you, when i change the method annotation to just GET, the post fails, but when i change it to just POST, the GET doesnt fail, and this method it IS being called via a GET by the template, as you see above, its embedded.  So, why doesnt the route fail on the GET, when i have this in the annotation?  `     * @Method({"POST"})`

Comment: I am posting to this form using ajax, so stahying on topic, would you alls say this php code passes muster, and that the problem must be in the request data itself?

Comment: wow, i got somethjing to work, i gutted the entire controller, started with a basic form, got it to pass isValid, so its not the request data, it is in the way im setting up the form object it appears.  Im trying ot addExtension(), how do i go about this correctly using `Forms::createFormFactory()`?   e.g. this works `$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)`, this breaks `form = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()`, so how do i add `$validator = Validation::createValidator();  form = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))` correctly then???

Comment: OOH, i got something good for us, when i add the `->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension());` i dont get the lame error  `Expected argument of type "null", "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request" given"` yay, that makes sense. i think this was the problem.  if i am sure of this, i will post this as teh answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks as if the validator extension, when used, was breaking, since the HttpFoundationExtension() wasnt being included.  Apparently to use either the validator, or the factory builder (not sure which) it needs this extension as well.

working example, copied from initial example, with working parts added.

```
    <?php
namespace ABC\DeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller,
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route,
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template,
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException,
    Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface,
    Symfony\Component\Form\Forms,
    Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationExtension,
    Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ValidatorExtension,
    Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation,
    Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length,
    Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank,
    Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response,
    ABC\CoreBundle\Controller\CoreController;

class DoSomethingController extends CoreController
{
    protected $debug = FALSE;

    public function doSomethingAction(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validation::createValidator();
        $builder = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
            ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
            ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension());


        $defaultData = array(
            'comment' => 'Type your comment here',
            'name' => 'Type your name here',
            'resources' => '{}',
            'warning' => 'Warning, your still in debug mode on your controller.php'
        );

        $resourcesInputType = $this->debug ? 'text' : 'hidden';

        $form = $builder->getFormFactory()
            ->createBuilder('form', $defaultData)
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('do_something'))
            ->add("emails", 'text', array(
                'label' => "Recipient's email address (separate with a comma)",
                'constraints' => array(// constraints here
                ),
            ))
            ->add('comment', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => "Leave a comment",
            ))
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => "Your name",
                'constraints' => array(// constraints here
                ),
            ))
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'label' => "Your email address",
                'constraints' => array(// constraints here
                ),
            ))
            ->add('copy', 'checkbox', array(
                'label' => "Send me a copy",
                'required' => false,
            ))
            ->add('cancel', 'button', array(
                'label' => "Cancel",
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-branded'),
            ))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => "Email Resources",
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-branded'),
            ))->add('resources', $resourcesInputType, array(
                'constraints' => array( // constraints here
                ),
            ))
            ->getForm()
            ->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();

            //run some data checks, then fire it off
            $something = $this->DoSomething($data);
            return $something;
        }
        // initial render
        return $this->render($this->someTemplate, array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```